# Compass Style - Difference between inline-block-list & horizontal-list

Tags: css, compass-sass

What are the differences between inline-block-list & horizontal-list (in Compass).

From my reading of the code, it seems that the main differences are horizontal-list-items are floated, and also the first and last items have 0 outer padding.

So what would be the uses of each type of list?  Which would be more appropriate to use for a horizontal nav bar for example?

Thanks very much.

Prembo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [horizontal-list li item's are floated](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/typography/lists/_horizontal-list.scss#L39) while the [inline-block (and inline) li items are not floated](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/blob/stable/frameworks/compass/stylesheets/compass/typography/lists/_inline-block-list.scss#L34) (but they use display: inline-block)